# nltk regular expression tokenizer

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, nltk

I tried to implement a regular expression tokenizer with nltk in python, but the result is this:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> text = 'That U.S.A. poster-print costs $12.40...'
>>> pattern = r'''(?x)    # set flag to allow verbose regexps
...     ([A-Z]\.)+        # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
...   | \w+(-\w+)*        # words with optional internal hyphens
...   | \$?\d+(\.\d+)?%?  # currency and percentages, e.g. $12.40, 82%
...   | \.\.\.            # ellipsis
...   | [][.,;"'?():-_`]  # these are separate tokens; includes ], [
... '''
>>> nltk.regexp_tokenize(text, pattern)
[('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '-print', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')]
```

But the wanted result is this:

```
['That', 'U.S.A.', 'poster-print', 'costs', '$12.40', '...']
```

Why? Where is the mistake?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1206#issuecomment-156470847

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should turn all capturing groups to non-capturing:

- `([A-Z]\.)+` > `(?:[A-Z]\.)+`
- `\w+(-\w+)*` -> `\w+(?:-\w+)*`
- `\$?\d+(\.\d+)?%?` to `\$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?`

The issue is that `regexp_tokenize` seems to be using `re.findall` that returns capture tuple lists when multiple capture groups are defined in the pattern. See [this *nltk.tokenize package* reference](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.regexp.RegexpTokenizer):

> **`pattern (str)`** – The pattern used to build this tokenizer. ***(This pattern must not contain capturing parentheses; Use non-capturing parentheses, e.g. (?:...), instead)***

Also, I am not sure you wanted to use `:-_` that matches a range including all uppercase letters, put the `-` to the end of the character class.

Thus, use

```
pattern = r'''(?x)          # set flag to allow verbose regexps
        (?:[A-Z]\.)+        # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
      | \w+(?:-\w+)*        # words with optional internal hyphens
      | \$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?  # currency and percentages, e.g. $12.40, 82%
      | \.\.\.              # ellipsis
      | [][.,;"'?():_`-]    # these are separate tokens; includes ], [
    '''
```