# Different results from one python code related to NLTK library on different computers

Tags: python, nltk, anaconda

I wrote the following code which works fine on my computer but return null on other computers. Could you please help me to solve this problem.

```
import string
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def preprocess(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    specialChrs={'\xc2',''} 
    pattern=pattern = r'''(?x)               # set flag to allow verbose regexps
              ([A-Z]\.)+         # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
              | \$?\d+%?
              | \$?\d+(,|.\d+)*
              | \w+([-'/]\w+)*    # words w/ optional internal hyphens/apostrophe
              |/\m+([-'/]\w+)*
            '''
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(pattern)
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
    print tokens
    realToken= [e for e in tokens if  len(e)>= 3 and len(e)<10]
    stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    stop_words = [w for w in realToken if not w in stopWords]
    filtered_words = [w for w in stop_words if not w in specialChrs]
    print filtered_words
   # final_words = [w for w in filtered_words if not w[0]=='0' and w[1]=='x']
    return filtered_words


str='I have one generalized rule, where in shellscript I check for all need packages, if any package does not exist, then install it other wise skip to next check. As I need to check and execute few other python as well shellscripts, I am using it. Is using shellscript for this is bad idea?'
preprocess(str)
```

These are part of my computer output:

> ['i', 'have', 'one', 'generalized', 'rule', 'where', 'in',
>   'shellscript', 'i', 'check', 'for', 'all', 'need', .......'idea']

other computers results:

> [('', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', ''),... ]

my computer information

> python 2.7.12 |**Anaconda 2.3.0** (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
>   [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
>   Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>
> import nltk
>
> print('The nltk version is {}.'.format(nltk.**version**))
>
> The nltk version is 3.2.1.

my friend computer

> python 2.7.12 |**Anaconda 4.1.1** (64-bit)| (default, Jun  29 2016, 11:42:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
>   Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>
> import nltk
>
> print('The nltk version is {}.'.format(nltk.**version**))
>
> The nltk version is 3.2.1.

Also, I test my code on another computer and I get the same result.

The information of that computer is:

> Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 26 2016, 21:01:49) 
>   [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: On a windows system (your friends'), strings are treated differently.

Comment: @alvas how about linux2 because I test it. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is answered[in this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353125/nltk-regular-expression-tokenizer)

you need to change the regular expression in this way and order to solve your problem.

```
`pattern = r'''(?x)          # set flag to allow verbose regexps
            (?:[A-Z]\.)+        # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
         | \$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?
         | \w+(?:-\w+)*        # words with optional internal hyphens
         |/\m+(?:[-'/]\w+)*
      '''`
```