# How can I write a correct nltk regular expression tokenizer in python?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I want to implement a regular expression tokenizer with nltk in python but I have following problems. I use [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353125/nltk-regular-expression-tokenizer) to write my regular expression.

```
import string
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def preprocess(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    pattern = r'''(?x)          # set flag to allow verbose regexps
        (?:[A-Z]\.)+        # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
     | \w+(?:-\w+)*        # words with optional internal hyphens
     | \$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?
     | \$?\d+%?
     |/\m+(?:[-'/]\w+)*
   '''
   tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(pattern)
   tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
   print tokens

str= 'i have one 98% 0.78 gener-alized 22 rule /m/0987hf /m/08876 i nees packages'
preprocess(str)
```

I got this

```
['i', 'have', 'one', '98', '0', '78', 'gener-alized', '22', 'rule', '/m/0987hf', '/m/08876', 'i', 'nees', 'packages']
```

I want this result

```
['i', 'have', 'one', '98%', '0.78', 'gener_alized', '22', 'rule', '/m/0987hf', '/m/08876', 'l', 'need', 'packages' ]
```

Also, if I want to remove digits what should I write in the regular expression?

Comment: Btw: Your abbreviation subpattern `(?:[A-Z]\.)+` is never going to fire if you feed lowercased sentences to the tokeniser.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that `\w` was designed to parse identifiers in programming languages (I guess) and therefore includes digits.

You should also be aware that order matters in a list of alternatives.
The most specific ones should go first, followed by the more general ones.

In your example, the second alternative in the pattern, `\w+(?:-\w+)*`, already matches `"98"` in `"98%"` or `"0"` in `"0.78"`.
After these fragments have matched, there is no pattern that would match `"%"` or the dot in `".78"`, so these are skipped by the tokeniser as token separators.

So, in this case, you should put the number-related subpatterns before the one with `\w`, otherwise it will "steal away" digit matches.

Unfortunately, there is no character-class shortcut for alphabetic characters only (like `\d` for digits only).
I have been using `[^\W\d_]`, which means "all characters, except for the ones that are not in `\w` or that are in `\d` or the underscore", which is the same as "all characters from `\w`, but without `\d` and without underscores". It's not an easily interpretable expression, however.

(Of course you can use `[A-Za-z]` if you think it's okay to tokenise `"Naïve"` into `["Na", "ve"]`.)

Comment: I combine number-related subpatterns  in this way`\$?\d+%?(,|.\d+)*`. How can I remove all number like _98%, 0.78 and 22_ from my string?

Comment: @user3092781 If you don't want numbers among the tokens returned, then leave out this subpattern. Anything that doesn't match is regarded as a token separator, and is omitted from the result.

Comment: @lenz The numbers are matched with `\w+(?:-\w+)* ` and I have 98 0 78 22 in the result.

Comment: Yeah, that's the point of my answer. Is there something I need to clarify?

Comment: You need to understand how the RegexTokeniser works. If you don't want numbers, you need to remove or edit all subpatterns that match numbers.