# Python: NLTK - regexp tokenizer produces empty output

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Im trying to tokenize the text available on NLTK text book (using python 2.7) but the output is not as expected. Is there something I am missing?

```
text = 'That U.S.A. poster-print costs $12.40...'

pattern = r'''(?x)     # set flag to allow verbose regexps
   ([A-Z]\.)+          # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
   | \w+(-\w+)*        # words with optional internal hyphens
   | \$?\d+(\.\d+)?%?  # currency and percentages, e.g. $12.40, 82%
   | \.\.\.            # ellipsis
   | [][.,;"'?():-_`]  # these are separate tokens; includes ], [
   '''

nltk.regexp_tokenize(text, pattern)


Output: 
 [('', '', ''),
 ('A.', '', ''),
 ('', '-print', ''),
 ('', '', ''),
 ('', '', '.40'),
 ('', '', '')]

Expected:
['That', 'U.S.A.', 'poster-print', 'costs', '$12.40', '...']
```

Comment: The comments are being included in the string. They aren't there in the actual program, right?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [nltk regular expression tokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353125/nltk-regular-expression-tokenizer)

Comment: @proyag Thanks for pointing that out. However, it doesn't handle %. The % symbol just goes missing in the tokenized text